# How can I create a pull request between branches with entirely different commit histories

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

I have two branches with entirely different commit histories, and I need to create a pull request **- NOT MERGE -** from one of them to the other. When I tried it gave me this: [image: github error message for entirely different commit histories]

I tried to push a mutual commit, but this is not working. What is the best practice for it? I'm a beginner and this is my first time dealing with it.

What should I do to create this pull request with all files contained in the `pull` branch?

Comment: What do you think a pull request will do?

Comment: I should do this to make reviewer able to see the code before merge it in master

Comment: You can't do this, period. A Pull Request is a different name for a Merge Request, and the result will be a merge. That's what a pull request does. If you have a few commits from branch `pull` that you'd like to add to `master` via a pull request, you'll have a create a new branch from `master`, cherry pick the relevant commits to it, and create a pull request from that.

Comment: `cherry pick the relevant commits to it` , should I push the code again to this branch ? or i have to choose some commit from `pull` branch ? there's a way to choose commit fast than push the code again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible to make a pull-request equivalent of `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`. You can do it like so:

```sh
# First, create a new branch based on main:
git switch -c history-merge main

# Next, merge your branch with the unrelated history into `history-merge`
#
# Resolve any merge conflicts at this time,
# and change the merge text to "Merge branch 'unrelated' into main".
git merge unrelated --allow-unrelated-histories

# Push your new branch:
git push -u origin history-merge
```

Once that's done, you can create a pull request from `history-merge` into `main`.

If you want it to be 100% seamless, choose the `rebase` option when you go to merge the PR. This will fast-forward `main` to the original merge-commit.